# how prevent to recurrence of two random numbers?

Tags: java, android, random, kotlin

please i have two TextView in android studio activity, and those Text has a Random number i need to multiple and get result, but while get random number, the duplicate of same number occur, how i can prevent that? this my code:

and i assigned the random to the TextView in this way:

```
object : CountDownTimer(timeToEndTwo, countDownForRandomTwo) {
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                num1.text = randomNumber().toString()
                num2.text = randomNumber().toString()

            }
```

and then comparing:
      if (Integer.parseInt(num1.text.toString()) * Integer.parseInt(num2.text.toString())
                    == Integer.parseInt(result.text.toString())) {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "right", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

and my function use to generate random number is :

```
   private  fun randomNumber():Int{
    val rand = Random();
    return rand.nextInt(10) +1
}
```

Comment: Filter the numbers to avoid dupes

Comment: Is your random number is stored somewhere or there is limit like between 1 to 10.

Comment: no, it is just from Method, it is a limit from 1 to 10, i update my post to add how i assigned the random to the TextView in this way:

Comment: how i can filter?, i need the two number in the two Textview not dupes with other, i mean the two, not the one number?